# "For doing" vs. "To do"

Tags: sentence-construction

I have some problems to relate some sentences to each other, specially when they get long. I observed "to" and "for" could be used for such relations, but don't know their proper usage and their differences.

For example I am writing a sentence

> In this paper, we propose a formalism **to construct** a wrapper **for extracting** [or to extract?] structured data from a Web page.

vs.

> In this paper, we propose a formalism **for constructing** a wrapper **to extract** [or for extracting?]  structured data from a Web page.

To avoid repetition of "for" or "to", in each sentence, for the second clause I used the other alternative.

What is the general rule? Are all the four combination of "to" and "for" in my sentence, correct?

---

By the way, how can I get mastered with sentences combination.

Answer (score 4):

You can use more clear phrases than just "for" and "to". You could try "in order to", "for the purpose of" and "intended to".

If I were writing this, I would say "In this paper, we propose a formalism to use in constructing a wrapper for the purpose of extracting structured data from webpages."