# "factory for producing aluminium strips" VS "factory to produce aluminimum strips"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. A initiates discussions with B to build a factory **for** producing aluminium strips.
> 2. A initiates discussions with B to build a factory **to** produce aluminium strips.

I am not certain whether this is a question well asked, or ever worthy of being answered. Is it a matter of which preposition should be used to modify factory?

Could you tell me which preposition is better here and why.

Comment: Given the idiosynchrocies of prepositions in the language, I don't see why it would be an unworthy question. In this particular case, I (US raised and educated, liberal arts but not an academic in English) don't see any meaning difference between these two sentences. I don't even see any connotation difference, in other words, I don't see any shade of difference in the meaning between the two. Does anyone have a different perspective, from Great Britain perhaps? (the spelling of aluminium is British, I presume, in the US it's spelled and pronounced aluminum.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["To do this" or "For doing this" to start explaining something?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84997/to-do-this-or-for-doing-this-to-start-explaining-something) Also [“To do” or “For doing”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65702/to-do-or-for-doing) and [“For doing” vs. “To do”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58801/for-doing-vs-to-do), and doubtless others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But the first one provide no substantial explanation. The second line seems better. However, honestly speaking, it did not drive away my doubt completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conveyed meaning is the same in both sentences. I parse them slightly differently, but the difference is inconsequential.

> ...to build a factory for producing aluminum strips.

In the first example, the purpose of the factory is the production of aluminum strips.

> ...to build a factory to produce aluminum strips.

In the second example, the production of aluminum strips is the purpose of *building* the factory.